# Error: Task requires a name at Gulp.Orchestrator.add

Tags: node.js, dependencies, gulp

I am building a Node Web App and testing it locally on Windows 10. At some point since my last successful run, this node module `orchestrator` seems to have been installed, presumably as some dependency. Now I am getting this error. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

```
C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal>gulp
[23:02:53] Requiring external module babel-register
C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:37
                        throw new Error('Task requires a name');
                        ^

Error: Task requires a name
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.add (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:37:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build_html.js:7:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at loader (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:126:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at requireDir (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal\node_modules\require-dir\index.js:116:33)
```

Alternatively, does it matter if I remove it? - Yes, I then get an error saying that Orchestrator cannot be found, and it seems to be referenced in my babel-register...

Update:

I am not sure if it is linked, but whenever I try to run npm update etc. I get peer dependency issues about reflect-metadata, yet if I try to instal it - see below:

```
C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal>npm i reflect-metadata
MakeSensePortal@0.0.1 C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\MakeSensePortal
+-- passport@0.3.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.3

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /browser-sync/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.9 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.
```

Comment: The problem might be with your gulp file mind posting it? Try looking in build_html.js line 7,  character 6 too.

Comment: I had a similar error due to a typo in my gulpfile. Instead of `gulp.task('name',['dep'],function(){})` I had `gulp.task('name' ['dep'],function(){})`. Whats the difference? A comma is missing after name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A comma was missing just after the task name in my case (same case as wassname) :

```
gulp.task('name' ['...']);
```

Correct version :

```
gulp.task('name', ['...']);
```

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes, left for lunch came back, and got this error.  So frustrating,  I spent about 30 minutes trying to figure out what was wrong.